# Groups across .Net core SignalR hubs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using Azure SignalR service for push notification and the implementation involves multiple hubs. In the .net framework, groups cannot be reused across hubs. Is it the same for .net core implementation using Azure Signal?

Answer (score 0):

> A group is a collection of connections associated with a name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#groups-in-signalr

I think - and I haven't tested this, so this is quite speculative, but if a group is nothing more than a collection of connections you could do something like:

```cs
// Some user defined hub
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    // Add to own group
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    // You'd need to use the DI to inject the other hubs into this one.
    MyOtherUserDefinedHub.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    MySecondOtherUserDefinedHub.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}
```

I think it would be easy to test this with a sample app.
This assumes that there is one connection id for each hub, which imo seems likely, but i did not find any resources about this online.

EDIT: Seems user Anton tested whether connection ids are shared between hubs - but apparently they're not. This means this proposal seems invalid and there is no built-in way.

Comment: This will not work at all. Hubs cannot be referenced outside of their own hub, and hubs do not know about connections to other hubs.

Comment: @Brennan Hubs surely can be referenced from outside, as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext also I believe connection ids are shared between hubs which means what i propose in this answer would be valid.

Comment: @sommmen i don't think connection ids are shared between hubs, because to access different hubs by the same client you need to instantiate new connection and i think different connections should have different connection ids

Comment: @Anton connections are - lets say, unique per browser tab if you will. But that does not mean that the ID for ChatHub for a certain connection won't be the same for OtherHub - which it just might

Comment: @sommmen okay, i tried it on my local to connect to two different hubs and got different connection ids. That is because server resolves connection id during the negotiation for two different http connections/requests for two hubs and it doesn't know anything about the tabs. I haven't checked this part of asp.net core code before, but for this case i went over the negotiation and found the place where connection id resolves and it makes random bytes sequence for each  negotiation "RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(buffer)" so i think different hubs won't have same connection id for same client

Comment: @Anton Well - Great to know, glad that you found some time to test this. In that case i think the answer to op's question would be a 'no'. I guess this would be something you would develop yourself, perhaps link 'users' (and their connection) to a custom 'usergroup' or something. Anyhow - I can't think of a built-in way.

Comment: @sommen i think while it isn't possible to directly add user to the group from different hub, it is possible to invoke some client methods in the group of different hub, so i think the part of this answer which says to invoke messages by the group is valid
Oh and i have just thought, we can post message to the client from one hub to ask it to add itself to the group of other hub. And then method of this client can invoke method of the hub to which it wants to add itself, will try it in evening

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core SignalR stores different collections of groups and connections for each hub type. But you can reference context of different hub using IHubContext. It will get you possibility to access clients and groups of other hub. Actually, it doesn't look like a good practice... It looks like it is usually used to send messages from controllers or background worker instead of other hubs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I haven't tried it in azure signalr, but tried modified example from docs on my local and it worked. Here is an example how you can accomplish this behavior

```
public class OtherHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _chatHubContext;

    public OtherHub(IHubContext<ChatHub> chatHubContext)
    {
        _chatHubContext = chatHubContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(chatHubContext));
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message, string group)
    {
        await _chatHubContext.Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("RecieveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

If you are interested in how it works internally, this class in the source code of SignalR is responsible for managing groups and connections
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/DefaultHubLifetimeManager.cs